# Excel VBA - Use of Replace when Importing SQL Statements from a text file

Tags: sql, excel, replace, vba

at first I may prevent that I may make some mistakes when writing in English, 'cos it's not my first language.

I'm learning a couple of things using Excel VBA and SQL to make my life easier at work. Quarterly, I have to produce a report that contains around 60 tables. So I'm writing a program that will help me getting some data from an Access Database, importing it in a new Excel workfile and formatting it in a nicer way for publication.
For it, I'm using an ADO connection, then I create a spreadsheet in my main excel file for each Table and the populate that sheet with one recordset.

To make debugging easier, I choose to put each of my SQL Statements in one Text file. I've build a function that read the content of that file. I've also put a Keyword, "STR1" and "STR2"to fill the "WHERE" clause of each SQL Statement, using some parameters entered by the User at the launching of my VBA program.
For that, I use a REPLACE after reading my text file and importing it in a String Variable.

My problemn is that for some files It makes the replacement and everything works fine (a new file is created and contains my Recordset), but for some of my text files, REPLACE doesn't replace my Keyword.

Here is an piece of my code, only the part that I think needs some cleaning. Can't post all because it contains some collections and class modules:

```
    ''' Version du programme ou on crée tous les fichiers dans form_2 et où on les exporte après/ version of my program where I create all Tables im my main file containing the code, export them in a new workbook and delete them

'Déclaration initiale/ Init of variables

Dim strMyPath As String, strDBName As String, strDB As String
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim db2 As New ADODB.Connection

'Appel de xx pour remplir anmois/ calling fct_anmois to fill my where conditions with the 5 couples years-quarter

Call fct_anmois(InputBox("Entre une valeur année", "Année"), InputBox("Entre une valeur codée mois: 21- 1er Trimestre; 22- 2ème Trimestre; 23- 3ème Trimestre; 24- 4ème Trimestre"))


'Quatres premiers Tableaux/ 4 1st Tables

' A entrer avec des parametres input utilisateurs que je définirai après: voir ma collection AnTrimes/ 

Dim STR1 As String

STR1 = "((Base1.Annee)=" & anmois.item(5).Ann & " ) And ((Base1.Mois)=" & Chr$(34) & anmois.item(5).Trime & Chr$(34) & ")"

Dim STR2 As String
STR2 = "((Base1.Annee)=" & anmois.item(1).Ann & " and (Base1.Mois)=" & Chr$(34) & anmois.item(1).Trime & Chr$(34) & ") or " & _
       "((Base1.Annee)=" & anmois.item(2).Ann & " and (Base1.Mois)=" & Chr$(34) & anmois.item(2).Trime & Chr$(34) & ") or " & _
       "((Base1.Annee)=" & anmois.item(3).Ann & " and (Base1.Mois)=" & Chr$(34) & anmois.item(3).Trime & Chr$(34) & ") or " & _
       "((Base1.Annee)=" & anmois.item(4).Ann & " and (Base1.Mois)=" & Chr$(34) & anmois.item(4).Trime & Chr$(34) & ") or " & _
       "((Base1.Annee)=" & anmois.item(5).Ann & " and (Base1.Mois)=" & Chr$(34) & anmois.item(5).Trime & Chr$(34) & ")"


'Debug.Print (STR1)
'Debug.Print (STR2)

'--------------
'L'Objet CONNEXION/ Connexion Object

''''''''''''''''Définition du Chemin d'accès vers la base de données/ Database workpath

strDBName = "Bulletin_Light.accdb"
strMyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
strDB = strMyPath & "\" & strDBName

''''''''''''''''Connect to a data source:
db2.Open ConnectionString:="Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=" & strDB

'''''''''''''''Chargement du vecteur syntaxe sql par appel de la procédure bosql/ Fill two vector, one containing text file name vartitres(), the other the content of the text file in which I have my SQL statement with a STR1/ STR2 in place of my WHERE Condition bouclesql(). It does it for each text file in a defined folder

Call bosql

Dim i As Integer
i = 0

''''''''''''''''Début de la boucle géante Par Feuille

For i = 0 To UBound(bouclesql)

    'Création de la nouvelle feuille/ Create a new worksheet names it like the text file ,checks if it already exists and deletes ii in case

Dim sht As Worksheet, shtname As String
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.count)) 'worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.count)
    If sht.name = Replace(vartitres(i), ".txt", "") _
        Then ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sht.name).Delete _
        Else sht.name = Replace(vartitres(i), ".txt", "")

    sht.Cells.Font.name = "Times New Roman"
    sht.Cells.Font.Size = 10


''' Correction du STR1/STR2 (s'il y en a) de la syntaxe SQL i/ Correction of the keyword STR1/STR2 in the WHERE Clause of my bouclesql() by the right content stored in these variables
'''Store the right statement in STRALL

''' de bouclesql(i)par la bonne condition sur le WHERE


Dim STRALL As String
If (vartitres(i) = "Tab1.txt" Or vartitres(i) = "Tab2.txt" Or vartitres    (i) = "Tab3.txt" Or vartitres(i) = "Tab4.txt") Then 
    STRALL = Replace(bouclesql(i), "STR1", STR1) 
Else 
    STRALL = Replace(bouclesql(i), "STR2", STR2)
End If

    'Debug.Print bouclesql(i)
    Debug.Print STRALL

'SQL Statement
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
        cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
        cmd.CommandText = STRALL
        cmd.ActiveConnection = db2


'''Ouverture du recordset

rs.Open cmd, , adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a case-sensitive problem? 
Your Code

```
[...] Replace(bouclesql(i), "STR1", STR1) [...]
[...] Replace(bouclesql(i), "STR2", STR2) [...]
```

The uppercase "STR1" or "STR2" may be a problem.
For Example:

```
    Dim strTry1 As String = "dog_cat_duck"
    Dim strTry2 As String = "Dog_Cat_Duck"

    MsgBox(Replace(strTry1, "dog", "car"))
    MsgBox(Replace(strTry2, "dog", "car"))
```

Replace strTry1 works.
Replace strTry2 don't work.

Try using `lCase / uCase` before using `Replace()`.

*Edit / Hint:*
This is terrible to read:

```
Dim STRALL As String
If (vartitres(i) = "Tab1.txt" Or vartitres(i) = "Tab2.txt" Or vartitres(i) = "Tab3.txt" Or vartitres(i) = "Tab4.txt") _
Then STRALL = Replace(bouclesql(i), "STR1", STR1) Else STRALL = Replace(bouclesql(i), "STR2", STR2)
```

Much better:

```
Dim STRALL As String
If (vartitres(i) = "Tab1.txt" Or vartitres(i) = "Tab2.txt" Or vartitres(i) = "Tab3.txt" Or vartitres(i) = "Tab4.txt") Then 
    STRALL = Replace(bouclesql(i), "STR1", STR1) 
Else 
    STRALL = Replace(bouclesql(i), "STR2", STR2)
End If
```

Comment: Such a noob!!! I've found the problem!! It was the STRALL filling part. My file names changed, and i've forgotten to change it in my IF clause. Many Many Thanks!!!

 I also got a problem. The part of the code supposed to delete a worksheet if it alredy exists doesnt work. It creates a new worksheet, can't name it and prompt me an error message. How can I solve this ?